# My code doesn't work. I have a problem with while loop

Tags: c, struct, printf, union

I want to get `Ala`. I get `A`. How to fix these?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void zad(char tab[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int size = strlen(tab);
    while(tab[i] != " ") {
        printf("%c", tab[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char word[20] = "Ala ma kota";

   zad(word);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please look for compiler warnings - `while(tab[i] != " ")` should be `while(tab[i] != ' ')` . Perhaps you get `'A'` and then it crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

char array and char types are different in c, the first uses `"` as a delimiter while the second uses `'`

So try this:

```
    while(tab[i] != ' ') {
```

Which should work for your example.

However, to make your code work more generally for different substrings (other than a space character) and for strings without a space in them, you need to use the size too, like this:

```
    while(i < size && tab[i] != ' ') {
```

to ensure that you don't attempt to read beyond the memory where your string resides.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:  `while(tab[i] != ' ' && tab[i])`

Use `' '` instead of `" "`